# Stale Element Reference in Protractor although conditional wait is added

Tags: javascript, testing, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Have problem under beforeEach function in my test class.
Click on the usersTab sometimes works fine, and sometimes returns `StaleElementReferenceException`.
Have tried `protractor.ExpectedConditions` like `presenceOf` or `visibilityOf` or `elementToBeClickable` but none worked in 100%.
I think that is caused by asynchronous and sometimes browser firstly want to click and afterwards wait - is it possible ?
Any idea how to handle it ?

```
var OnePage = require('../pages/one_page.js');
var SecondPage = require('../pages/second_page.js');

describe('Test', function () {

    var onePage;
    var secondPage;
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

    beforeEach(function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        onePage = new OnePage();
        browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(onaPage.userLogin), 5000);

        onePage.setUser('login@login');
        onePage.setPassword('password');
        onePage.login();


        secondPage = new SecondPage();
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(secondPage.usersTab), 10000);
        usersPage.usersTab.click();
    });
```

I am using `jasmine:2` and `protractor:2.2.0` .

Answer (score 1):

When I first started to build my Test Suite I ran into a similar issue and it took me a while to track down a solution. When you initialize the Page Object using a standard `var` in your `beforeEach` function it can hold on to an old instance when the 2nd or higher test is run. No idea how long it typically takes or what really triggered the hiccup in my tests, it was always random for me. The only way I could solve this was to use the `this` keyword in my `beforeEach` function like the example below. When the `beforeEach` function is executed the instance is correctly renewed in each test.

---

NOTE: In my conf.js file under `onPrepare` I have the following function setup to tell Protractor if the page that follows is an Angular page or not:

```
global.isAngularSite = function(flag) {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = !flag;
};
```

---

```
var OnePage    = require('../pages/one_page.js');
var SecondPage = require('../pages/second_page.js');

describe('Test', function () {

    beforeEach(function () {
        isAngularSite(true);

        this.onePage    = new OnePage();
        this.secondPage = new SecondPage();
        this.ec         = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

        browser.wait(this.ec.presenceOf(this.onePage.userLogin), 5000);

        this.onePage.setUser('login@login');
        this.onePage.setPassword('password');
        this.onePage.login();

        browser.wait(this.ec.visibilityOf(this.secondPage.usersTab), 10000);
        usersPage.usersTab.click();
    });

    it('', function() {

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try chaining the actions with each other so that they execute serially once the first one is completed resolving its promise. Here's how -

```
beforeEach(function () {
    browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;

    onePage = new OnePage();
    browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(onaPage.userLogin), 5000).then(function(){
        onePage.setUser('login@login');
        onePage.setPassword('password');
        onePage.login();
    });

    secondPage = new SecondPage();
    browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(usersPage.usersTab), 10000).then(function(){
        usersPage.usersTab.click().then(function(){
            //If you want to verify something after click, do it here.
            browser.sleep(500);
        });
    });
});
```

If you want the second page actions to be done only after first one, then chain them together.

```
    browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(onaPage.userLogin), 5000).then(function(){
        //Actions of OnePage
    }).then(function(){
        //Actions of second page
        secondPage = new SecondPage();
        browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(usersPage.usersTab), 10000).then(function(){
            usersPage.usersTab.click().then(function(){
                //If you want to verify something after click, do it here.
                browser.sleep(500);
            });
        });
    });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(secondPage.usersTab), 10000).then(function(){
usersPage.usersTab.click();`    did not help  ...  it worked 3 times, and 4 time failed with the same error.

Comment: Are you verifying something after click event? If so add in your code inside the click promise. If not then its better to wait for click to be executed before moving on using a promise. Updated code. Hope it helps.

Comment: after click event the bunch of tests will be runned,  problem is that I can't do this click             `usersPage.usersTab.click();`  althought I waited for it.

Comment: One more thing, if you want to click on the `usersPage.usersTab`, then you should be waiting for it to be visible using wait() to click and not wait for `secondPage.usersTab`, right? If you can share your html it'll be helpful too.